# How long can store and use OAuth v1, v2 token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm building software which constantly pull data from spreadsheet user has provided access to.
I still live in era when api key was enough to pull as long as I wanted.

1. I'm a bit confused what are long live tokens. Are they endless?
2. Can I think about access token as old but goodie  api key?
3. Do I need to "harass" user every 60 days to provide me with fresh oauth authorisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OAuth 1.0, the access token lives forever.  As long as your user does not revoke it, you can use it continuously.

However, for OAuth 2.0, the access token does expired.  Once the access token expired, you will need to refresh it with the refresh token.

Here is more detail: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer